# Using pystone.py to test python in Windows 10 vs. python in WSL

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Intel's version of the **Anaconda** python 3 distribution in Windows 10, and the standard python 3 that comes with **Ubuntu 16.04** in WSL. The **pystone.py** benchmark gives 139131 pystones/second when run in a Windows 10 **cmd** window, and 206011 p/sec when run in WSL. Why is the WSL version almost 50% faster? My CPU is an i5-4590.